# Is there any valid approach to adjust the statistical power taking the inflation of type 1 error into account?

Tags: references, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

I'm conducting some simulation analysis under different correlation structures where H0: absence of interaction component in the model.

I computed type 1 error rate under the null hypothesis at some instance, and I saw that the type 1 error rate is inflated. Assume that the expected value is 5%, and I got type 1 error = 15% for example. Then, under the alternative hypothesis, I introduced some variance in the model interaction component, and there, I got a higher statistical power. In numbers, let's say I got 90% power.

What I understand is that this 90% is not the true statistical power, and some proportion of it is contributed by type 1 error inflation. I understand that the true statistical power should be less than 90%. Assume that the true (or adjusted) statistical power is x%. I want to know whether there's any valid approach to compute x taking the 15% - 5% = 10% type 1 error rate inflation into account.

Please provide me references, if there's any such valid approach.